# koalas Column assignment doesn't support type ndarray

Tags: pandas, spark-koalas

All - I am trying to add a new column to an existing koalas dataframe but it fails with the error above. The value I am assigning with is an np array. Am I missing something at all? This works well with pandas.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
df = ks.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
# works so far!!

df["target"] = iris.target ## this errors out!
```

TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type ndarray

Am I missing anything here?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even df.assign did not solve the problem and I was getting the same error:

I had to do this:

```
ks.reset_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames')
# convert target to a koalas series so that it can be assigned to the dataframe as a column
ks_series = ks.Series(iris.target)
df["target"] = ks_series
ks.reset_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames')
```

Answer (score 0):

### My bad:

I misread where and what the issue was. Try the following:

```
...
df.assign(target=iris.target)
```

<s>Could you try the following:</s>

```
...
df = ks.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=list(iris.feature_names))
...
```

Looking into the [load_iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) documentation, they make a not of converting the returned array into a list.

Comment: the problem is when adding the "target" value. The original dataframe gets created without issues

Comment: Ah, I see! Because of koalas did you try to use the `assign` function (NOT `append`)?